# Конструктор копирования в throw

Tags: devc++, исключения, классы, c++, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток.
Допустим, есть try-блок, где передается локальный объект по значению (знаю, что это плохо)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CL
{
public:
    CL()
        {
                cout<<"CL()"<<endl;
        }
        CL(CL&)
        {
                cout<<"CL(CL&)"<<endl;
        }
        ~CL()
        {
                cout<<"~CL()"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        try
        {
                CL cl;
                throw cl;
        }
        catch (CL clcop)
        {
                cout<<"cl catched"<<endl;
        }
}
```

В каком порядке здесь должны вызываться конструктор копирования для clcop и деструктор для cl? Сначала, как я понимаю, копируется локальный cl во временный объект throw'а, но потом у разных компиляторов появляются различия. VS2008 вызывает конструктор копирования для clcop, а потом деструктор для cl, devcpp же вызывает сначала деструктор, а потом копирует. Как должно быть на самом деле?
P.S. не стал кидать через явный вызов CL(), так как тогда из-за оптимизации копирования не происходит

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я предлагаю класс немножечко модифицировать

```
class CL
{
public:
    CL()
        {
                cout<<"CL()" << this <<endl;
        }
        CL(CL&)
        {
                cout<<"CL(CL&)" << this <<endl;
        }
        ~CL()
        {
                cout<<"~CL()" << this <<endl;
        }
};
```

В этом случае видно, кого именно создают и кого удаляют. Я компилировал с помощью g++ (формально, это тот же mingw) и получил такой вывод:

```
CL()0x7fff21efc32f
CL(CL&)0x23bb090
~CL()0x7fff21efc32f
CL(CL&)0x7fff21efc32f
cl catched
~CL()0x7fff21efc32f
~CL()0x23bb090
```

замечается странность, что вроде создается объект и удаляется с одним адресом дважды, но это просто стек.
А больше никаких странностей - объект создан, скопирован. После этого он не нужен и компилятор может вставить его удаления. А может и чуточку позже. Если я правильно помню стандарт, то он это должен сделать до конца функции. Компилятор мог вставить и позже удаление объекта, но в данном случае он решил красиво переиспользовать стек и поместить туда объект такого же типа.

Я думаю, что если Вы для своего кода сделаете тоже, то увидите, что в этом хаосе есть порядок.

Comment: Почему конструктор копирования не CL( const CL& ) ?

Comment: потому что так также можно. Стандарт, пункт 12.8.2. более того, там еще пара вариантов возможна - `volatile X&` и `const volatile X&`.

Comment: Просто дело в том, что cl является не только локальной переменной функции, но и переменной try-блока, т.е. можно предположить, что она должна разрушаться при любом выходе из этого блока, в том числе при вызове throw. Только решение, когда объект будет копироваться (до разрушения cl или после), видимо, остается на усмотрение компилятора

Comment: а как можно скопировать объект после его разрушения?:)

А так - стандарт только определяет, к какому моменту должен быть разрушен объект (в данном случае до выхода с блока). Но компилятор может вставить разрушение объекта как в конце блока, так и сразу после того, как объект больше не нужен. Просто не все компиляторы могут делать такой сложный анализ.

Замечу, что в том примере, что у Вас, компилятор может  выкинуть вызов деструктора и вставить вывод в консоль и коррекцию стека прямо по месту.

Comment: Никак )
Но только здесь копируется временный объект, который получился в throw, а разрушается локальный объект cl (throw всегда создает специальный временный объект, который существует до момента обработки исключения, т.е. это два разных объекта), и факт, что порядок копирования и разрушения меняется от компилятора к компилятору

Comment: Это поведение компилятора как то влияет на работоспособность Вашей программы?